# Sqoop: Create Link Fails With Number Format Exception

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to create a link, using the generic-jdbc-connector, in Sqoop for Hadoop. However, when I try to I get a number format exception:

```
sqoop:000> show connector
+----+------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Id |          Name          | Version |                        Class                         | Supported Directions |
+----+------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| 1  | generic-jdbc-connector | 1.99.6  | org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcConnector | FROM/TO              |
| 2  | kite-connector         | 1.99.6  | org.apache.sqoop.connector.kite.KiteConnector        | FROM/TO              |
| 3  | hdfs-connector         | 1.99.6  | org.apache.sqoop.connector.hdfs.HdfsConnector        | FROM/TO              |
| 4  | kafka-connector        | 1.99.6  | org.apache.sqoop.connector.kafka.KafkaConnector      | TO                   |
+----+------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
sqoop:000> create link --connector generic-jdbc-connector
Invalid command invocation: Missing required option: c
sqoop:000> create link -c generic-jdbc-connector
Exception has occurred during processing command
Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException Message: For input string: "generic-jdbc-connector"
```

I used an example from http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.7/user/Sqoop5MinutesDemo.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below command ,it should work .

```
sqoop:000> create link -connector generic-jdbc-connector
```

Issue: You have have tried multiple times.

```
    1st time : In your command you have given --connector in place of -connector
    2nd time : In place of -connector you have given -c which is wrong, that is the reason you are getting exception.
```